# Split whole B-tree

Tags: data-structures, split, b-tree

Anyone know how to split whole B-Tree (not split node) into two sub trees as low cost as possible? Currently I do this by dividing all elements which sorted in tree into 2 arrays, then rebuild 2 sub trees from that, but this solution does not seem to take a low cost as I want. Any idea?

Comment: Does someone have any idea???

Comment: If you split the root node (or any node) you directly get two subtrees. Is that not sufficient? Otherwise it would help if you describe which problem you are trying to solve: why do you need two subtrees, why are you having a single tree, why a B-Tree.... ?

Comment: Define the operation of splitting a B tree. The usual [definition of B tree](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap19.htm) defines splitting a node but not splitting the tree itself.